# Cast de vetor char para ponteiro

Tags: c++, cast

Galera como funciona um cast em um vetor `char` para um ponteiro `int`?
por exemplo:

```
char vetor[2];
int *p;
p = (int *)&vetor;
```

Alguém pode me explicar essa linha?

Comment: Esse código irá pegar cada elemento do vetor char, converter pra inteiro e colocar no vetor de inteiros..

Comment: Até onde entendo, isso cria um ponteiro para um valor inteiro que por sua vez é o endereço de memória vetor de char (do primeiro elemento do vetor). Fora de contexto assim, não serve pra nada.

Answer (score 4):

Primeiramente é necessário entender o que exatamente um ponteiro armazena, independentemente do tipo do ponteiro ele terá como principal função armazenar um endereço, que pode ser qualquer local da memória como variáveis, funções de seu programa e até mesmo funções externas como de DLLs e outros. Em maquinas 32 bits os ponteiros tem geralmente 4 bytes, que pode apontar qualquer lugar dos primeiros quase 4GB de memória e em maquinas 64 bits os ponteiros costumam ter 8 bytes, que é o suficiente para mapear qualquer lugar da memória de quantidades muito maiores.

Quando você tem um tipo com um ponteiro (por exemplo: `void* out int*`), você apenas esta informando ao compilador, quantos bytes a partir do endereço esta representando o valor. Veja esta imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como você pode ver na imagem acima, o ponteiro p2 apenas aponta para o endereço 5 e pelo fato de seu tipo ser `int` (4 bytes), quando você vai obter o valor em que o ponteiro p2 esta apontando ele vai obter os bytes do endereço 5 + os do tamanho informado ao ponteiro (4 neste caso), ou seja, o valor do `int` será os valores das posições da memória 5, 6, 7 e 8.

Quando você tem um ponteiro `void`, este ponteiro continua com sua função de armazenar endereços, porem não é possível obter valor, pois o tipo `void` não representa nenhum tamanho, assim a única utilidade de se ter um ponteiro `void` é o armazenamento do endereço na memória.

Mas lembre-se novamente, independentemente se o tipo do ponteiro é void ou int ele continua a ocupar os 4 bytes (ou 8 em 64 bits) para armazenar o endereço em que ele esta apontando.

No caso do seu código, quando você aponta `int *p;` para `char vetor[2];` o ponteiro `int *p;` somente armazenara o endereço de `char vetor[2];`, este cast `p = (int *)&vetor;` é somente para passar o endereço de vetor como se fosse o mesmo tipo, porem não será possível você obter o valor desse endereço sem fazer outro cast, pois ao tentar obter o valor de `*p` como se ele fosse um `int`, ele acabaria obtendo o valor de dois bytes a mais que não pertence ao `char vetor[2];`, veja o porque:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como você pode ver na imagem acima o `char vetor[2];` ocupa 2 bytes (pois cada `char` ocupa 1 byte), quando você passa o endereço do `char vetor[2];` para `int *p;` com um cast e tentar obter o valor de `int *p;` ele consideraria que o valor seria o endereço em que o *p aponta mais o tamanho do tipo a ele informado (neste caso int = 4 bytes), ou seja, ele obteria os dois bytes da *array* vetor, e ainda obteria dois bytes a mais de fora da `array` vetor para formar um valor `int`.

Se você quer passar caracteres, números ou strings em forma de ponteiro `int`, isto é possível, mas depois você tem que fazer outro cast para representar novamente o valor, veja este exemplo.

```
// Transforma em ponteiro int
char vetor[] = "Hello World!";
int *p = (int *)&vetor;
// Trannsforma em ponteiro char
char *text = (char*)p;
printf("%s", text);
// Output: Hello World!
```

Porem se o foco é somente passar um endereço, é melhor que se utiliza ponteiro `void` que não vai obter bytes a mais na memória do que o tamanho determinado. Veja este exemplo de ponteiro `void` que aponta para função:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int GetFive()
{
    return 5;
}

typedef int (*FUNÇÃO)();

void MostraRetornoDaFunção(void* função) // Esta função recebe uma função como um ponteiro void
{
    int (*fun)() = (FUNÇÃO)função; // Aqui é necessario fazer um cast para mostrar que o *void é uma função
    int a = fun();
    printf("%d", a);
}

int main()
{
    void *funcPtr = &GetFive;
    MostraRetornoDaFunção(funcPtr);

    printf("\n");
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Então basicamente o cast servira apenas para passar o endereço para o ponteiro como se a variável apontada fosse do mesmo tipo, e o tipo servira apenas para saber quais bytes após o endereço apontado será usado como valor.

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: 11/10 Perfeita Explicação