# Cast de ponteiro

Tags: c, ponteiro

```
void    *ft_memchr(const void *s, int c, size_t n)
{
    while (n > 0)
    {
        if (*(unsigned char *) s == c)
        {
            return ((void *)s);
        }
        s++;
        n--;
    }
    return (NULL);
}
```

O que seria este `*(unsigned char *)s`?

Eu entendo que é um *cast* porque é um `void` e tal, mas o que eu não consigo entender e nem achar material para entender é esses ponteiros, por exemplo o primeiro `*` já não sei o que é, mas pelo que eu vi a existência dele já me deixa totalmente em dúvida da existência do segundo ponteiro.

Comment: Talvez ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70843/112052 | https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90855/112052 | https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/266831/112052

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Qual é a finalidade do void em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97138/qual-%c3%a9-a-finalidade-do-void-em-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `(unsigned char *)` é um cast de um endereço qualquer para um endereço do tipo unsigned char*.

Um `unsigned char` possui um byte de tamanho.

O primeiro `*` é para desreferenciar o endereço de `s`.

Como o endereço de `s` agora é interpretado como um `unsigned char` vai ser desreferenciado um byte a partir do endereço.

E esse byte é comparado com a variável `c`.